# Target table column with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a Wordpress theme with a scoreboard (5 of them in a row). For some reason the CSS I am using is targeting the bottom tables, but will not effect the column width of the first two.

The website is here: http://berlinbravesbaseball.de/tester/2016/04/16/berlin-braves-baseball-hat-eine-neue-webseite/

The CSS being used is:

```
 table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child{width: 120px;}

 .execphpwidget{ vertical-align: top;}

.widget th, .widget td {
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.widget .sam-column1{
    width: 120px;
  }

.sam-table-fixer > tr:first-child > td:first-child{
     width: 120px;
}
```

Whatever I do, it affects all tables, but I cannot expand the width of the first column of the first tables. I need to target it specifically. What's going wrong?

Comment: Just a `td:first-child { width: 120px; }` works for me. All first columns are then 120px wide. Also with the more specific selector `table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child` it seems to work. What's your issue?

Comment: You'd think it would, but for some reason the top tables still won't force the first two tables to have a 120px width? They seem to be forced into having a 20% width for each of the 5 columns.

Comment: Which is the first table, the one with "Aktuelle Ergebnisse"? Of course, the more specific one wouldn't work since the first row only contains a single cell with `colspan="5"`.

Comment: Yes - the column with "Aktuelle Ergebnisse" is the column I wish to target.  I want to expand the first column, which mostly contains Team Names (such as "2. BL BB"). I would like the column to expand to the same width as it is in the table below - the one beginning with "Verbandsliga".

Answer (score 0):

Using colspan in tables prevents other width settings in other rows. Also, your default td width is set to 25%, but you have 5 cells in a row. All your CSS contradicts therefore. Additionally, you are using a fixed table layout, which makes the whole table use the widths of the first row (which doesn't have a layout due to the colspan).

To actually have the first cells in "normal" rows be 120px wide, use a colgroup declaration:

```
<colgroup>
  <col width="120">
  <col width="40">
  <col width="40">
  <col width="40">
  <col width="40">
</colgroup>
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Excuse me - the column expanded, however istead of taking the width I give it, it expands significantly more. <col width="120"> creates a column of 147px width, <col width="106"> creates a column width of of 110. Any indication why this might be happening?